# Relatório JasperReport - Página em branco - Relatório PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jasper-reports

É o seguinte eu criei o relatório no jasperReport criei um parâmetro lá ,com isso os dados deste relatório ele ta pegando do banco (Mysql) e exibindo o/

Mas quando coloco pra exibir na minha página JSF os dados ficam em branco um formato pdf em branco ..
Segue meu código

No console do servidor apache ,exibe esta mensagem ...

> Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException

```
public RelatorioBean() {
    this.context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
}

public void exporterPdf() {

    stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Ireport/ireport_1.jrxml");
    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    params.put("cpf_Funcionario",params);
    params.put("invoice_logo",params);
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {

         JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Ireport/ireport_1.jrxml" ));          
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,params, Conexao.getConexao());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);            
       JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print,false);
        view.setExtendedState(JasperViewer.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        view.setVisible(true);




        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
                                                    //attachment
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;filename=ireport.pdf");
        response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.getOutputStream().close();
        context.responseComplete();

    } catch (JRException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(RelatorioBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha ao exportar: " + ex.getMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RelatorioBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha ao exportar: " + ex.getMessage(), "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


    }
```

Gostaria dos conselhos de vocês, por gentileza !!

Comment: nas linhas do params.put("cpf_Funcionario" eu andei pesquisando ..são parâmetros ..lá do jasper e tal..e o invoice_logo foi pq o apache tava dando um erro tbm em cima dele..tem haver ,sobre uma imagem do relatorio,  cara já testei tudo...

Comment: retirei o código da primeira linha.e tbm retirei params.put (invoice_log) ,mesmo assim ainda surge a mensagem do  - _itálico java.net.MalformedURLException

Comment: alguém pra me ajudar ??

Comment: ei galera..estou seguindo um tutorial para exportar o meu relatório , e não entendo o por que fica dando erro -- neste trecho    `  
    String Caminho = Faces.getRealPath("default/ireport.jasper");`

Comment: Os parâmetros devem ser do tipo Map. Você pode obter uma boa referência seguindo as explicações do David Buzzato aqui: [Trabalhando com Ireport](https://davidbuzatto.com.br/2010/10/09/jasperreports-trabalhando-com-relatorios-em-java-parte-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Segue solução do código:

Ajuste conforme a sua necessidade:

```
this.context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
this.response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

String caminho;
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
if ("nao".equals(relatorio.getGeral()) && "periodo".equals(relatorio.getTipoDeRelatorio())) {

caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/vendas/vendas.jasper");

parametros.put("Id_Cliente_Venda", relatorio.getCliente().getCodigo());
parametros.put("data_inicio", relatorio.getDataInicial());
parametros.put("data_fim", relatorio.getDataFinal());
parametros.put("CodEmpresa", autenticacaoBean.getUsuario().getEmpresa().getCodigo());

//JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(caminho);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, conexao);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);

response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=relatorio.pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();

context.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Seria muito importante ter uma explicação sobre o código!